# How to get client customer id after authentication to adwords

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-ads-api

Am using python client library in my app. The user authenticate to his adwords account and approve permissions. I would to retrieve the client customer id of the authenticated user. When the user is authencticated i get the credentials relative to the user and i would like to get the client_customer_id tiedto that credentials.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'm not sure why people upvoted it. To clarify, are you asking about how to get the client customer ID of a single account or an MCC account? Are you asking about the client customer ID of the very account you authenticated? Or, are you asking about the client customer ID of an account within the account you authenticated with?

Answer (score 0):

How version of adwords api you are using?

I'm using the version v201607.

You can use the get_account_hierarchy to gets the account hierarchy under the current account.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201607/account_management/get_account_hierarchy.py

Comment: Am using  v201702, the question was to get the client customer id of the curretly connected user and i found how to do it : i used the customer service :
 oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient( client_id, client_secret ,refresh_token)
    # Initialize the AdWords client.

    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
        developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent)
customers = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService').getCustomers()
customer= customer[0]
customer_id = customer2['customerId']